# Defining variables in asm

Tags: variables, assembly, x86, gnu-assembler, att

Is the following a valid way to define variables in `asm`?

```
.globl main
.globl a, b, c, d

a: .byte    4
b: .value   7
c: .long    0x0C    # 11
d: .quad    9

main:
    mov     $0,         %eax
    add     a(%rip),    %eax
    add     b(%rip),    %eax
    add     c(%rip),    %eax
    add     d(%rip),    %eax
    ret
```

For example, is it required/suggested to have a `.TEXT` section? How exactly does `a(%rip)` resolve to the value of `$4`? That seems almost like magic to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default section is `.text`; lines before any section directive assemble into the `.text` section.  So you do have one, and in fact you put everything in it, including your data.  (Or read-only constants.)  Normally you should put static constants in `.rodata` (or `.rdata` on Windows), not in `.text`, for performance reasons.  (Mixing code and data wastes space in the I-cache and D-cache, and in TLBs.)

---

It doesn't resolve to an immediate `$4` at assemble time, it resolves to an address.  In this case, using a RIP-relative addressing mode.  See [what does "mov offset(%rip), %rax" do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29421766/what-does-mov-offsetrip-rax-do) / [How do RIP-relative variable references like "[RIP + _a]" in x86-64 GAS Intel-syntax work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54745872/how-do-rip-relative-variable-references-like-rip-a-in-x86-64-gas-intel-sy) for more about the fact that it means "address of symbol `a` with respect to RIP", not actually RIP + absolute address of the symbol.

In other cases, the symbol `a` does generally resolve to its (32-bit) absolute address when used as `add $a, %rdi` or something.

**It's only *at runtime* that the CPU loads data (which you put there with directives like `.long`) from that static storage**.  If you changed what was in memory (e.g. with a debugger, or by running other instructions) before `add     c(%rip),    %eax` executed, it would load a different value.

You put your constant data in `.text`, along with the code, which is generally not what you want for performance reasons.  But it means the assembler can resolve the RIP-relative addressing at assemble time instead of only using a relocation that the linker has to fill in.  Although it seems GAS chooses *not* to resolve the references and still leaves it for the linker:

```
$ gcc -c foo.s
$ objdump -drwC -Matt foo.o

foo.o:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <a>:
   0:   04                      .byte 0x4

0000000000000001 <b>:
   1:   07                      (bad)  
        ...

0000000000000003 <c>:
   3:   0c 00                   or     $0x0,%al
        ...

0000000000000007 <d>:
   7:   09 00                   or     %eax,(%rax)
   9:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
   b:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
        ...

000000000000000f <main>:
   f:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  14:   03 05 00 00 00 00       add    0x0(%rip),%eax        # 1a <main+0xb>    16: R_X86_64_PC32       a-0x4
  1a:   03 05 00 00 00 00       add    0x0(%rip),%eax        # 20 <main+0x11>   1c: R_X86_64_PC32       b-0x4
  20:   03 05 00 00 00 00       add    0x0(%rip),%eax        # 26 <main+0x17>   22: R_X86_64_PC32       c-0x4
  26:   03 05 00 00 00 00       add    0x0(%rip),%eax        # 2c <main+0x1d>   28: R_X86_64_PC32       d-0x4
  2c:   c3                      retq
```

(Attempted disassembly of your data as instructions happens because you put them in `.text`.  `objdump -d` only disassembles `.text`, and non-immediate constants are normally placed in `.rodata`.)

Linking it into a executable resolves those symbol references:

```
$ gcc -nostdlib -static foo.s    # not a working executable, just link it without extra stuff
$ objdump -drwC -Matt a.out
... (bogus data omitted)

000000000040100f <main>:
  40100f:       b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  401014:       03 05 e6 ff ff ff       add    -0x1a(%rip),%eax        # 401000 <a>
  40101a:       03 05 e1 ff ff ff       add    -0x1f(%rip),%eax        # 401001 <b>
  401020:       03 05 dd ff ff ff       add    -0x23(%rip),%eax        # 401003 <c>
  401026:       03 05 db ff ff ff       add    -0x25(%rip),%eax        # 401007 <d>
  40102c:       c3                      retq
```

Note the 32-bit little-endian 2's complement encoding of the relative offsets in the RIP+rel32 addressing modes.  (And the comment with the absolute address, added by objdump for convenience in this disassembly output.)

---

BTW, most assemblers including GAS have macro facilities, so you could have used `a = 4` or `.equ a, 4` to define it as an assemble-time constant, instead of emitting data into the output there.  Then you'd use it as `add $a, %eax`, which would assemble to an `add $sign_extended_imm8, r/m32` opcode.

---

**Also, all your loads are dword sized (determined by the register operand), so only 1 of them matches the size of the data directives you used.**  Single-step through your code and look at the high bits of EAX.

Assembly language doesn't really have variables.  It has tools you can use to implement the high-level-language concept of variables, including variables with static storage class.  (A label and some space in `.data` or `.bss`.  Or `.rodata` for `const` "variables".)

But if you use the tools differently, you can do things like load 4 bytes that span the `.byte`, the `.value` (16-bit), and the first byte of the `.long`.  So after the first instruction, you'll have EAX += `0x0c000704`  (because x86 is little-endian).  This is totally legal to write in assembler, and nothing is checking to enforce the concept of a variable as ending before the next label.

(Unless you use MASM, which does have variables; in that case you'd have had to write `add eax, dword ptr [a]`; without the size override MASM would complain about the mismatch between a dword register and a byte variable.  Other flavours of asm syntax, like NASM and AT&T, assume you know what you're doing and don't try to be "helpful".)