# When and How is %rip-relative addressing resolved?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, memory-address, relative-addressing

Take the following assembly program:

```
_start:
    mov myvar,       %rax
    mov myvar(%rip), %rax
    mov myvar(%rip), %rax
    mov myvar(%rip), %rax
    mov myvar(%rip), %rax
```

The produces the following when run in `gdb`:

```
!0x00000000004000b0  ? mov    0x600107,%rax
 0x00000000004000b8  ? mov    0x200048(%rip),%rax        # 0x600107
 0x00000000004000bf  ? mov    0x200041(%rip),%rax        # 0x600107
 0x00000000004000c6  ? mov    0x20003a(%rip),%rax        # 0x600107
 0x00000000004000cd  ? mov    0x200033(%rip),%rax        # 0x600107
```

Of course, it's not surprising that all the `myvar` references resolves to `0x600107`. Where (or perhaps when is a better question) do the `%rip`-relative items get resolved to an actual address? How does that process work at a high level?

**Related**: [Why does this MOVSS instruction use RIP-relative addressing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44967075/why-does-this-movss-instruction-use-rip-relative-addressing).

Comment: It's resolved at run-time by the CPU, that's why it's a special addressing mode.  If it was just a source-level thing, it wouldn't need separate syntax.

Comment: See [what does "mov offset(%rip), %rax" do?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29421766).  Also [Can rip be used with another register with RIP-relative addressing?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48124293) explains some details about the machine-code encoding.  Also https://wiki.osdev.org/X86-64_Instruction_Encoding#32.2F64-bit_addressing.  [How do RIP-relative variable references like "\[RIP + \_a\]" in x86-64 GAS Intel-syntax work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54745872) has some examples of the machine code.

Comment: Anyway, are you asking how the CPU decodes machine code that uses a RIP-relative address?  Or how the tools (e.g. assembler or linker) figure out the right relative address in the first place?

Comment: @PeterCordes I would say a bit of both, but if the assembler/linker basically 'defers' it to the cpu then yea that would be really cool to understand (at a basic level) how that works and is decoded.

Comment: Go read https://wiki.osdev.org/X86-64_Instruction_Encoding#32.2F64-bit_addressing then.  x86-64 repurposed one of the 2 redundant ways to encode `[disp32]` (with/without SIB); the shorter one (without a SIB) means `[rip+rel32]` instead of `[disp32]`.  The CPU knows the address of the end of the instruction so it can do the math.